# Mongodb searching between dates of different months

Tags: mongodb

I'm searching documents 2 dates, If I'm searching for a single month I'm getting the result, but when I'm searching between 2 different month I'm getting nothing

```
db.dates.find({
   $and: [{
     "date": {
       $gt: '18-07-2016'
     }
   }, {
     "date": {
       $lt: '25-01-2016'
     }
   }]
 }).pretty();
```

I'm getting result for the above one

```
db.dates.find({
       $and: [{
         "date": {
           $gt: '18-07-2016'
         }
       }, {
         "date": {
           $lt: '02-08-2016'
         }
       }]
     }).pretty();
```

not getting for this one

Comment: Did you insert using `new Date()`? Comparison should be done using the same, not just a string. E.g. `{"date":{$gt:new Date("2016-07-18")}}`

Comment: I am surprised, how you can get the result for the first one as  '25-01-2016' is smaller than than 18-07-2016

Comment: Use ISODate or new Date, then you will not get any result. Try this.

Comment: @vineet in my collection its saved in this format "date" : "01-08-2016"

Comment: You can not query for date if it is not saved in proper format in your db.

Comment: @Shrabanee I think the same, I need to get all and then convert them to ISO and then filter using IF condition

Comment: You have to do something like that to achieve what you want.

Comment: It's no surprise the first one is working with enddate being before startdate: the clause for date is getting overriden. As other said, use an object for both clause or use $and. First is better. And ISODate,  of course

Answer (score 1):

Also, There is no need to use $and, you can use like below :-

```
   db.dates.find(
                                {
                                    "created":{
                                                $lt:new Date("<date>"),
                                                $gt:new Date("<date>")
                                                }
                                 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("18-07-2016"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("02-08-2016"));    
db.dates->find(array("date" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
```

Comment: I think you should explain your answer as well.